# Query time in django debug toolbar

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

I see time of query QUERY = 'SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) AS [__count] FROM ... in Django debug toolbar. Is it pure perfomance of database or dirty time that includes handling of query by Django and third-party libraries?

Answer (score 0):

As seen on the docs:

> SQL
>
> ```
> classdebug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLPanel
> ```
>
> SQL queries including time to execute and links to EXPLAIN each query.

This means it doesn't include django processing time.

https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/panels.html#sql